# Program which asks if you want beer

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote a program that asks if you want a beer (only larger than or equal to 18 years old).
My assembler reports some problems.  I'm a beginner in 8086 assembly.

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA

  Welcome DB 'Hello man, How old are you?',13,10,'$'                                    
  beer DB 'Did you want to drink a beer?(y/n)',13,10,'$'
  old DB 'You cant drink becuste are you young',13,10,'$'   
  yes DB 'Ok thanks, pay 5$ in cash',13,10,'$' 
  no DB 'Ok, so **** you off!',13,10,'$'


    .CODE

    Welcom:  

        MOV AX, @DATA              
        MOV DS, AX                 
        MOV AH, 9                   
        MOV DX, OFFSET Welcome     
        INT 21h                    

        MOV AL, 1
        INT 21h       

        CMP AL, 18
        JB older 
        CMP, AL, 18 
        JAE drink

        MOV AX, 1 
        INT 21h  
        CMP AL, 'y'
        JE ye
        CMP AL, 'n'
        JE n

      older:


            MOV DX, OFFSET old 


      drink:  


            MOV DX, OFFSET beer



      ye:  


            MOV DX, OFFSET yes


      n:

            MOV DX, OFFSET no

     xx:

         MOV AX, 4ch 
         INT 21h     
         END Welcome
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what is the question being asked here?

Comment: What problems does your assembler report? Regarding what lines of code? You'll get better answers if you supply all relevant information.

Comment: Which assembler? What errors? This program will only ever print the 'no' text even when bugs are fixed (Can you tell why?).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a comma after the CMP in `CMP, AL, 18`. And you don't need the 2nd CMP anyway because a conditional jump doesn't affect the flags from the previous CMP.

You probably shouldn't be using another conditional jump either, but you'll learn that later.

---

As for your second question, you put "END Welcome" instead of "END Welcom", which I'm guessing set the program start in the DATA section at the string beginning "Hello". The 'e' is character code 65 (hex). In general, it's not a good idea to use labels which are so similar. Maybe make the data string label "greeting", and leave "Welcome" for the code, in which case you can leave your END statement as it is.

Comment: The assambler(emu8086) execute the code but when I runed it the message "unknown opcode skipped: 65
not 8086 instruction - not supported yet.
" jump.
Who is the instruction that not supported yet?