# emu86- declaring variables is compiled wrong

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

i am new to asm and emu86. i wrote the folowing code

```
org 100h

;variabls
var1 dw 21

;start of the program
main:

    mov     ax,var1
```

however when i am emulate ax stores the value a100h

[image]

i am expecting to ax to be 21 but instead ax stores the value 0xa100.

what did i do wrong?

i declared var1 to be equal 21 and moved it to ax. but somehow ax equal 0xa100

Comment: Are you sure you set a breakpoint right after that instruction?  The code in your disassembly window looks like execution ended up somewhere else after decoding later bytes in memory as other instructions, some of which also modified AX.  (Your program doesn't exit with a DOS call, or with `ret` which works in .com executables because the top of stack ("return address") is a pointer to code that makes an exit call.)

Comment: [Sourced guess](https://gcallah.github.io/Emu86/area.html): if you want the value of a variable and not its address, put it in square brackets.

Comment: Also you seem to be executing through the location where the variable is stored(?). Maybe jump around it or something...

Comment: @teapot418: emu8086's assembly dialect is MASM-like; `mov reg, symbol` is a load even without square brackets.  And `A100` wouldn't be the offset.  Oh, the offset would be `0100` because that data is the first 2 bytes of the program, where it gets executed as code...  As 0Signal points out, `15` is the start of a 3-byte instruction that "eats" the A1 opcode for the `mov ax, moffs16` instruction.  Yeah, put the data later.  [Assembly (x86):  db 'string',0 does not get executed unless there's a jump instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30561366)

Answer (score 3):

1. `.com` files are plain binary.
2. `org 100h` sets starting offset for the code.
3. `var1` is erroneously treated as code not program's data.
4. Variable definition `var1 dw 21` in memory looks like: `15 00`.

   The instruction that starts with code `15` is:

   `adc ax,imm16`

   This instruction uses 3 bytes, and the 3rd byte is taken from
   the line `mov ax, var1` which in memory is `A1 00 01` (`mov ax, moffs16`, `0100` is `var1` offset). Remaining bytes `00 01` form instruction `add [bx + di], al` (`00 /r, ADD r/m8, r8`).
5. Solution is to use `jmp` to skip the bytes `15 00` (`var1 dw 21`).

```
org 100h            ; .com file

jmp start           ; EB 02

    var1 dw 21      ; 15 00

start:
    mov ax,var1     ; A1 02 01

    cmp ax,0        ; 3D 00 00

    mov ax,4c00h    ; B8 00 4C
    int 21h         ; CD 21

    ret             ; C3
```

Comment: *Somehow byte A1 is shared with 2 instructions* - When the CPU decodes this sequence of bytes, the `A1` byte is part of the `ADC AX, 0A100` instruction we see in the disassembly.  The CPU will start decoding the next instruction at `00 01`, a memory-destination `add` with `AL` as the source.  So yes, machine-code instruction boundaries (*from that start-point for decoding*) are out of sync with source lines.  x86 machine code is a byte stream that's not self-synchronizing; there are no instruction boundaries unless/until you pick a starting point to decode from.

Comment: I write faster than think sometimes. :D I updated my answer, I hope it is better now. :)