# Why does code in MS-DOS Debug does not run and makes the prompt disappear?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, dosbox

I'm writing this code in DOSBox-0.74-3, making use of MS-DOS Debug and once I run it makes the prompt disappear and it does not do anything else.

```
mov cx,16
db 0d,0a,"placeholder",0d,0a,24
mov ah,09
mov dx,(Memory address of db)
int 21
loop (Memory address of mov ah,09)
mov ah,4c
int 21
```

What it should do is show the message 'Placeholder' 22 times, but it is not doing it.
I have been able to run other simple codes as this one.

Comment: Format your code

Comment: Make up your mind. Either *once I run it makes the prompt disappear and it does not do anything else*, or it *shows  an error*. It can't do both at the same time - it's not possible to *not do anything else* and *shows an error*. The two are opposites.

Comment: Separate code and data!

Comment: I prepared examples at https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20240212/ - 1.txt: Move data to behind code, assembles `mov dx` again to fill in the offset only known after the entire code is assembled. 2.txt: Put the data at a considerable distance from the code so we can predict during the assembly a valid offset that we can place the data at. 3.txt: Skip over data using a `jmp` (size of the jump + length of the data must be predicted or fixed up afterwards again). 4.txt: Input that works only with lDebug, using lDebug's variables to fix up the `mov dx` instruction with the correct address automatically.

Comment: duplicate of [Assembly (x86):  db 'string',0 does not get executed unless there's a jump instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30561366) / [Segmentation fault when using DB (define byte) inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55642600)

Answer (score 3):

```
mov cx,16
db 0d,0a,"placeholder",0d,0a,24
mov ah,09
```

If you're starting to run your code at the first line above, it's probably *not* going to do what you expect when it starts executing the *data* created by the `db` statement.

By all means *manipulate* data with your code but it's a rather bad idea to attempt to execute it as if it were code :-)

So the *first* thing I would do is get that data out of the code area, with something like (added labels to make the code more readable, use of `debug` means you'll probably have to pre-calculate memory locations unless you want to enter some instructions more than once):

```
         mov cx, 16
again:   mov ah, 09
         mov dx, my_data
         int 21
         loop again
         mov ah, 4c       ; 'mov ax, 4c00' for zero return code.
         int 21

my_data: db 0d,0a,"placeholder",0d,0a,24
```

There may still *be* issues with that code (such as returning a non-zero code in `al`) but you at least won't be attempting to execute data as code.

Comment: The exit code can be `mov ax, 04c00h`, to return an exit code of 0.

Comment: A problem is you have to enter the `mov dx` twice because you do not know the address to enter at the time you first enter it. Debug doesn't support labels.

Comment: @ecm, I added the labels just to make the code more readable, I wouldn't be using debug for assembling code anyway :-)