# Segmentation fault when using DB (define byte) inside a function

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, machine-code

I was curious what would happen if I put `db 0x41` in the `.text` section, instead of in `.data` where it would normally belong.  It segfaults, but why exactly?

The bits of code below were compiled, linked and executed in Mint 19.1 with `nasm` and `ld`.

No segfault:

```
global _start
section .data
db 0x41
section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 60    ; Exit(0) syscall
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Segfault:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    db 0x41
    mov rax, 60     ; Exit(0) syscall
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

I'm using the following commands to assemble, link and run it:

```bash
nasm -felf64 main.s -o main.o
ld main.o -o main
./main
```

Comment: Because you put your byte into the execution path so the CPU tried to decode it as instruction which faulted. Use `objdump -d` to see what it means. Put it after your code if you insist on it being in `.text`. Or move the `_start` label to the beginning of your actual code. Yes, `.text` is read-only but you did not attempt to write to it so that's fine.

Comment: Since you're using NASM, it optimizes `mov rax,60` into `mov eax,60`, so the instruction doesn't have the REX prefix you'd expect from the source.  (That would have given you a SIGILL from 2 REX prefixes for one instruction.)  Your manually-encoded REX prefix for `mov` does change it into a `mov` to R8D instead of EAX, though:  `41 b8 3c 00 00 00       mov    r8d,0x3c`.  Check with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.

Comment: Yeah and loading `r8d` instead of `eax` will of course remove the loading of the function number for the system call so it will no longer be an `exit` and it will return to continue execution except there is no more valid code to execute. Segfault.

Comment: I cleaned up your edit.  One thing I didn't mention in the edit log message is that you wrote *was being treated as an instruction instead of actually defining a byte.*   It *does* actually "define" (or emit / assemble) that byte into the output at the current position, it's not an "instead of".  If you did `movzx ecx, byte [_start]`, you'd load the `0x41`.  (`.text` is read-only unless you use some other `ld` options, so you couldn't normally modify it.)

Comment: The "problem" is that it's not magically skipped by execution.  That's actually a feature if you have an old assembler that doesn't know newer mnemonics like perhaps [`serialize`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/serialize), `db 0x0F, 0x01, 0xE8`.  (A good example since it has no operands to encode by hand.)  Or if you want your asm source to work with old assembler versions people might have installed on their systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you tell the assembler to assemble arbitrary bytes somewhere, it will.  `db` is a pseudo-instruction that emits bytes, so `mov eax, 60` and `db 0xb8, 0x3c, 0, 0, 0` are exactly equivalent as far as NASM is concerned.  Either one will emit those 5 bytes into the output at the current position.

**If you don't want your data decoded as (part of) instructions, don't put it where it will be reached by execution.**  (For example, put it in `section .rodata` or `section .data` before or after your code, like in the question.  You can switch back and forth between `section .text` and other sections, if you want your asm source to define static/global data near each function that uses some.)

---

Since you're using NASM<sup>1</sup>, it optimizes `mov rax,60` into `mov eax,60`, so the instruction doesn't have the REX prefix you'd expect from the source.

**Your manually-encoded REX prefix for `mov` changes it into a `mov` to R8D instead of EAX**:
`41 b8 3c 00 00 00       mov    r8d,0x3c`

(I checked with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` instead of [looking up which bit is which in the REX prefix](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix).  I only remember that REX.W is `0x48`.  But `0x41` is a REX.B prefix in x86-64).

So instead of making a `sys_exit` system call, **your code runs `syscall` with EAX=0, which is `__NR_read`**.  (The Linux kernel zeros all the registers other than RSP before process startup, and in a statically-linked executable, `_start` is the true entry point with no dynamic linker code running first.  So RAX is still zero).

```
$ strace ./rex 
execve("./rex", ["./rex"], 0x7fffbbadad60 /* 54 vars */) = 0
read(0, NULL, 0)                        = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

**And then execution falls through into whatever is *after* `syscall`, which in this case is `00 00` bytes that decode as `add [rax], al`, and thus segfault.**  You would have seen this if you'd run your code inside GDB.

---

Footnote 1: **If you'd used YASM which doesn't optimize to 32-bit operand size**:

Intel's manuals say that it's illegal to have 2 REX prefixes on one instruction.  I expected an illegal-instruction fault (#UD machine exception -> kernel delivers SIGILL), but my Skylake CPU ignores the first REX prefix and decodes it as `mov rax, sign_extended_imm32`.

Single-stepping, it's treated as one long instructions, so I guess Skylake chooses to handle it like other cases of multiple prefixes, where only the last one of a type has an effect.  (But remember this is not future-proof, other x86 CPUs could handle it differently.)

---

Related / same bug in other situations:

- [Assembly (x86): <label> db 'string',0 does not get executed unless there's a jump instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561366/assembly-x86-label-db-string-0-does-not-get-executed-unless-theres-a-jum)  in a BIOS MBR boot sector
- [Unknown opcode skipped: 66, not 8086 instruction - not supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145673/unknown-opcode-skipped-66-not-8086-instruction-not-supported-yet) in EMU8086

Comment: When you wrote "YASM doesn't optimize", I assumed you meant that it encoded `mov rax, imm` as `48 b8 imm64`. But then you said it is executed as `mov rax, imm32`. For a minute, I thought you had made a mistake. :-)  But then I guessed that YASM does a *partial* optimization and encodes it as `48 c7 c0 imm32`.

Comment: @prl: oh yes, worded more explicitly.  It always chooses the shortest encoding for the instruction you ask for (based on the numeric value), but it *won't* change the operand-size to something you didn't ask for.  In Intel syntax, `mov r64, sign_extended_imm32` and `mov r64, imm64` are both 64-bit operand-size. In fact, in YASM `mov rdi, symbol` chooses the sign_extended_imm32 encoding, so it won't link into a PIE executable.  (NASM chooses `mov r64,imm64` with a 64-bit absolute relocation for runtime fixup). Yet another reason to never write `mov r64, symbol`, always `mov r32` or `LEA [rel]`.

Comment: What happens if there is a REX prefix followed by a non-REX prefix? Like segment overrides, `repe`/`repne`, `lock`, `asize`/`osize`.

Comment: @ecm: Again, the manual says REX must be the last prefix.  On SKL, `41 66 b8 ff ff ff ff` ignores the REX entirely, and writes AX=-1, with the single-step stopping after the imm16 of `mov ax,-1`.  It doesn't write R8W despite the REX.B=1, like it would with prefixes in a valid order.  I didn't test extensively, and of course there's zero guarantee that any future CPU, or existing other CPUs, will behave like Skylake.  If you want to dig deeper, a separate Q&A about behaviour of real CPUs with invalid prefix combos would be a good place to post results.

Comment: What NASM does is dum. Why it doesn't do that for dw, dd etc. It is super useful to define strings locally, so you can 1. Use local names and 2. easily see what is in the string variable.

Comment: @user13947194: you *can* use `section .rodata` / `.local_string: db "hi",0` / `section .text` in the middle of your function if you want, with the machine code going into `.text` but the global constants or variables going into another section.  The label "scoping" doesn't care about switching sections so you can still use dot local labels.  That label-scoping also works if you put the a function's data right after it instead of in the middle.  You could even make a macro that switches sections and back on one line if you like mixing things.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Peter Cordes. Now I have a better understanding of NASM assembly. Anything inside section .text is executable code. Why they did this? Maybe to allow you to write pure machine code, so that you can have access to machine instructions not implemented in NASM assembler. Or maybe to just allow you to optimize machine code as you like, or avoid NASM optimizing machine code for you, At any rate, thank you.