# Segmentation Fault in x86_64 Assembly: Issue with System Calls

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm

I simply trying to print "Hello!" on screen but i encountered a **SegmentationFault** error.
I have two programs one works fine and other gives error.

Code which works fine :

```
global  _start
    section .text

_start:

    
    mov rdi,1           
    mov rsi,hello_world     
    mov rdx,13  
    mov rax,1           
    syscall

    ; exit(result)
    mov rax,60          
    mov rdi,0           
    syscall

hello_world:    db "Hello World!",10
```

code which gives **SegmentationFault**:

```
global  _start
    section .text

_start:

    
    mov rdi,1           
    mov rsi,hello_world     
    mov rdx,13  
    mov rax,1           
    syscall

hello_world:    db "Hello World!",10

    ; exit(result)
    mov rax,60          
    mov rdi,0           
    syscall
```

the desired output for second code should be : Hello world!

but it gives:[Segmentation Fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaYsN.png)

Can someone explain me why the first code works fine and second one gives error.

Comment: If you place `hello_world:    db "Hello World!",10` in the middle of the code like you have in the bottom example - that data (string) is going to be executed as instructions after the first syscall is done. You want to move your data out of the path of execution. If you want data in the middle of code (not sure the use case) then you can always `jmp` over it.

Answer (score -1):

As Michael said it in his comment, the problem comes from this `hello_world:    db "Hello World!",10`.

To understand why that happens, you first have to know how programs are represented in memory. Wikipedia's [Object File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) page may be a good start to understand this in more details. But to be short in this example we are interested in 2 segment types: the data segment and the code segment.

**The code segment** (or text segment) of a program contains the instructions the machine has to execute to run the program. Usually this code segment becomes read-only when loaded into the main memory (when you execute the program). This is mainly for security reasons, you can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX).

**The data segment** of a program contains initialized static variables. The string "Hello World!" in your program is a good example of such a variable.

So to write an assembly example "with the good practices", you should make use of these 2 different segments, a Hello World example might be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm).

Now when a program is executed, idea is that the CPU will load the operation pointed by the program counter (PC), execute it, and increment the PC to make it point to the next instruction. This works because the CPU knows the size of an instruction, and can hence correctly increment the PC. In your code this all goes well, the CPU will correctly execute until it comes to `hello_world:    db "Hello World!",10`. There, the next 10 bytes are set to "Hello World!". So when the PC will be incremented, it will point to somewhere in this string. Maybe at first it will encounter valid instructions in the string, but at some point it will encounter a memory instruction with an address pointing at a memory region that is not allocated to this program. A segfault will be issued when trying to dereference this address. If you want to know exactly what instruction and address are being used, the comment of Peter Cordes gives you a good start on how to do it.

Comment: "`db` will try to write to a read-only segment" This is nonsense, `db` directives write at assemble/build time (just like any instructions you assemble will write machine code to the current section), so they can equally well write to read-only data or code sections.

Comment: x86 isn't a stack machine.  It's a register machine.  (Abstract models of computation don't distinguish between CPU registers vs. RAM, so I think the closest standard abstract model is RASP.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine).

Comment: As ecm says, `db` is processed at assemble time, not run-time.  For example, `db 0x90` is exactly equivalent to `nop`, each assembling one byte into the current section of the object file being created.  So your bullet point 1. applies, not 2.  There's already a Q&A about it: [Segmentation fault when using DB (define byte) inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55642600)

Comment: Forgot to say earlier, if the bytes weren't a valid instruction, you'd get SIGILL rather than SIGSEGV.  They probably *are* a valid instruction (most bit-patterns decode as something), but one that dereferences a register that happens not to be holding a valid pointer.  e.g. `00 00` is `add [rax], al`.  Or a privileged instruction (also segfaults on Linux), or a jump somewhere.  You can check with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to disassemble the machine code, or single-step it in a debugger, if you're curious what it actually is.  The early part of the upper-case ASCII range is REX prefixes (0x4x)